# rotate image shows "Out of memory" exception

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

```
   public Bitmap rotateImage()
    {

      try
      {                      
          curImgHndl.CurrentRotationHandler.Flip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

      }

    return objCurrImageHandler.CurrentBitmap;
    }
```

When an image is rotated several times (5 or more) using this function then it shows the error message
“Out Of Memory” .
To ratate an image in c#.net 4 I used ImageFunctions.dll. Decompiling the dll I have got the followings.

only a portion of the whole code is given that is used for rotation

```
public class RotationHandler 
{
   private ImageHandler imageHandler;

   public void Flip(RotateFlipType rotateFlipType)
   {
      this.imageHandler.RestorePrevious();
      Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap.Clone();
      bitmap.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType);
      this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap = (Bitmap) bitmap.Clone();
   }
}
```

How can I solve it?

the following method solve the problem as lazyberezovsky suggested.

```
 public void Flip(RotateFlipType rotateFlipType)
  {
    this.imageHandler.RestorePrevious();
    this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType);
 }
```

But another problem in brightness method.

```
    public void SetBrightness(int brightness)
    {
        Bitmap temp = (Bitmap)_currentBitmap;

            Bitmap bmap = (Bitmap)temp.Clone();
            if (brightness < -255) brightness = -255;
            if (brightness > 255) brightness = 255;
            Color c;
            for (int i = 0; i < bmap.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bmap.Height; j++)
                {
                    c = bmap.GetPixel(i, j);
                    int cR = c.R + brightness;
                    int cG = c.G + brightness;
                    int cB = c.B + brightness;

                    if (cR < 0) cR = 1;
                    if (cR > 255) cR = 255;

                    if (cG < 0) cG = 1;
                    if (cG > 255) cG = 255;

                    if (cB < 0) cB = 1;
                    if (cB > 255) cB = 255;

                    bmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb((byte)cR, (byte)cG, (byte)cB));
                }
            }
            _currentBitmap = (Bitmap)bmap.Clone();


    }
```

This method works for some images and doesn't work for other images and shows the following error
"SetPixel is not supported for images with indexed pixel formats."

It would be very much helpful if you could provide efficient and workable methods for rotation, crop and brightness.
please help again.

Comment: I haven't analyzed your logic in detail but Bitmap class need to be disposed. Dispose Bitmap instances where appropiated.

Answer (score 3):

As Claudio mentions, you need to make sure you are disposing of any unused `Bitmaps`.

```
public void Flip(RotateFlipType rotateFlipType)
{
   this.imageHandler.RestorePrevious();
   Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap.Clone();
   this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap.Dispose(); // dispose of current bitmap
   bitmap.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType);
   Bitmap clone_map = (Bitmap) bitmap.Clone();
   bitmap.Dipose(); // dispose of original cloned Bitmap
   this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap = clone_map;
}
```

You could probably simplify this to just:

```
public void Flip(RotateFlipType rotateFlipType)
{
   this.imageHandler.RestorePrevious();
   Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap.Clone();
   this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap.Dispose(); // dispose of current bitmap
   bitmap.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType);
   this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap = bitmap;
}
```

Comment: this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap.Dispose() releases memory but creates another exception(Parameter is not valid). See details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177414/undo-image-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

Why not to rotate current bitmap, instead of creating copies?

```
public class RotationHandler 
{
   private ImageHandler imageHandler;

   public void Flip(RotateFlipType rotateFlipType)
   {
      this.imageHandler.RestorePrevious();
      this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType);
   }
}
```