# How to fix 'Parameter is not valid' exception after Cloning and Disposing source Bitmap

Tags: c#

I have the following two classes:

```
public class ImageHandler
{
    private Bitmap _currentBitmap;
    private Bitmap _bitmapbeforeProcessing;

    public Bitmap CurrentBitmap
    {
        get
        {
            if (_currentBitmap == null)
            {
                _currentBitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
            }
            return _currentBitmap;
        }
        set { _currentBitmap = value; }
    }

    public string CurrentBitmapPath { get; set; }

    public void ResetBitmap()
    {
        if (_currentBitmap != null && _bitmapbeforeProcessing != null)
        {
             Bitmap temp = (Bitmap)_currentBitmap.Clone();
            _currentBitmap = (Bitmap)_bitmapbeforeProcessing.Clone();
            _bitmapbeforeProcessing = (Bitmap)temp.Clone();
        }
    }

    internal void RestorePrevious()
    {
        _bitmapbeforeProcessing = _currentBitmap;
    }
 }
```

And:

```
public class RotationHandler
{
    private ImageHandler imageHandler;

    public void Flip(RotateFlipType rotateFlipType)
    {
        this.imageHandler.RestorePrevious();
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap.Clone();
        this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap.Dispose(); // dispose of current bitmap
        bitmap.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType);
        this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap = bitmap;
   }
 }
```

When `ResetBitmap()` is called after rotation, it shows:

> Parameter is not valid

But if:

```
this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap.Dispose();
```

is commented then it works fine.  But if `Flip()` method is called several times then Out Of Memory exception occurs.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Although Bitmap is a C# object, it is really a win32 object, hence, you must call Dispose() when you are done with it.

You are doing:

```
_CurrentBitmap = _CurrentBitmap.Clone();
```

When you should be doing:

```
_Temp = _CurrentBitmap.Clone();
_CurrentBitmap.Dispose();
_CurrentBitmap = _Temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just dealt with a similar problem with the same error.

Calling `Clone()` on a `Bitmap` object creates only a shallow copy; it will still reference the same underlying image data, so calling `Dispose()` on one of the objects will delete the data for both the original and copy.  Calling `RotateFlip()` on a disposed `Bitmap` object results in the exception you see:

> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid

One way to fix this is to create a new `Bitmap` object based on the original one, rather than using `Clone()`.  This will copy the image data as well as the managed object data.

For example, instead of:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap.Clone();
```

Use:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(this.imageHandler.CurrentBitmap);
```

Note that if the source bitmap object is null, this will also lead to an `ArgumentException`, so in general the following is better (I've renamed the source bitmap to `currentBitmap` for brevity):

```
Bitmap bitmap = (currentBitmap == null) ? null : new Bitmap(currentBitmap)
```